# Hall effect output to a level voltage or other useful output

Tags: analog, sensor

I am trying to take the output of a Hall effect sensor (latching or non) that is sensing magnets on a wheel and turn it into a level DC voltage that varies with the speed of the wheel. The only limitation I have is any circuitry must be analog. My ultimate goal is to make a speedometer with this information and I have a way of achieving that if I can get the Hall effect sensor converted into a varying DC voltage.

If you have any suggestions on how to do this, or  possibly alternative to it that is analog I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: "*The only limitation I have is any circuitry must be analog.*" This makes your question sound like a homework question where you have been given a constraint. If it is then you need to show your attempt, what you have found in your research and where you are stuck.

Comment: Why not to use linear hall effect sensor?

Answer (score 1):

I think you find it hard to locate a more reasonable device than this: -

[image]

So, don't be fooled by the name: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use op. amp. 1 to square the signal.

The output of op. amp. 1 is a square wave signal whose frequency is your signal: the speed.

At the output of op. amp. 1 put an RC low pass filter.

At the output of the RC filter, put op. amp. 2

Set the gain of op. amp. 2 in order for the signal to fit the next stage of the circuit.

---

Transform chain:

Speed --> Frequency --> RC filter --> Analog signal